# How to update Apk installed completely with new one in end user device

Tags: android, apk

Any1 plz help me ... in android

How to update the complete  apk which is already installed in end user device....

Say for ex: Android market app which is installed in device is completly changed to googleplay apk...

how to do that....

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Google Market/Play is a bad example as it has it's own updater that can not be used by regular apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload a compleatly new apk (like whole new project) just keep the same Key when signing and the same Package name (e.g. com.example.App) and it will update like magic.

Comment: I think he means the total APK, not the name.

Comment: @PoweRoy He can still do that, he would just have to keep the same key and Package.

Comment: Than that should be your answer instead of the app_name changes ;)

Comment: @PoweRoy Ok, I think I might of misread his question a little.

Comment: @Nstorim: if i do like that can i update apk even in user device...?

Comment: @MohamedHishamIbnHanifa Yes, just remember same key and same package name. Make sure to mark this question as answered if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what NStorm mentioned, but if you have [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) installed you can open up command prompt and do an adb install like the following:

```
   adb install -r file.apk
```

As long as its the same signing key and the same package name you will be able to install it that way.  If you have a different signing key you will have to uninstall the application on the phone first to install it.  The -r flag means reinstall and keeps all the previous data for that application.  This of course only works if you have adb installed and if you physically have the phone and cord in your hands.

The other choice you have is to email the phone the application, or to host it on a URL page and have the end-user go to it and install it that way.  You can easily upload it to a server and text or email out a link to the end user and they can reinstall it that way.  You will still need to have the same signing key else they will have to uninstall the application.

In summary, you have three ways of doing it without going through the Google Play marketplace.

1. Upload to a server, and text/email out a link to the apk.
2. Email the apk as an attachment, have the user download and install.
3. Use ADB.